# Einstein bot & routing by skills

Tags: liveagent, einstein, chat, bots

I am trying to configure the Einstein chat bot to route the customer to the right agent after choosing the department in a menu. Where do I configure this routing?

Where in the bot do I say *if the client pressed sales than route to an agent with the "sales" skill*?

I have already connected the bot in the chat button settings, but where does the routing configuration according to client's choose happen?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that this routing-issue will be solved with the #Summer19 Release: docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_service_bots_transfer.html